# jQuery widget ------ the context of this?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

When making a jQuery widget can you please explain the concept of `this`?

When I make  a variable `this.shell` in the  function  `_createMyShell` why is it available to the whole widget.  shouldn't it only be available to the function?

or is it making a property for the context of the widget object? Please can you explain?

```
function ($, undefined) {    
  $.widget('hhh.myTestWidget', {    
    version: 'alpha',

    _create: function () {
        this.element.addClass('hhh.myTestWidget');
        this._createMyShell();
        this._renderMyStuff();    
        //console.log(this.element);
        //console.log(this.options);        
    },

    _createMyShell: function () {     
        this.shell = $('<div>this is my shell</div>');
    },

    _renderMyStuff: function () {    
        this.shell.appendTo(this.element);    
    }    
  });    
}(jQuery));
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if your code wasn't a widget, `this.shell = foo` would simply be adding a new property `shell` to the variable `this`.

However `this` is determined based on the *context* of the function call, and the jQuery UI widget wrappers ensure that `this` is always set to the new object that's created that contains all of the shown methods.

Answer (score 0):

`this` in your function represent the object `Widget`. Every function in your widget are assigned to the same object. `_createMyShell` must be declared inside your widget like that : `Widget.prototype._createMyShell = function(){}`. Yet i can't assure you it is exactly like that, there is other possibility but the context of your function [`this`] will be the widget (some method like `bind`, `call` and `apply` can rebind the context).

Now that you know `this` is the widget object, you can assign properties to it, like `shell`. But since the other functions are attached to the widget and you attached the `shell` to the widget, you can access it when your are inside the said widget or when you have access to the widget object.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're confused because functions in Javascript are objects. But within functions `this` is a reference to the executing context. If you simply call...

```
function doSomething() {
    console.debug(this);
}
doSomething();
```

you get the window object of the browser. But as an exception, when the function is a property of an object, `this` is bound to that object. A function gets `this` bound to it when it is instantiated with `new`. To show the difference, both `this`' in the next example share the same reference:

```
var a = function() {
    this.doSomething = function() {
         console.debug(this);    
    }
}
var b = new a;
b.doSomething();
```